# Java-er should use something if ORM (JPA, Hibernate, etc) is evil

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, jdbc

I must be confused between ORM and JDBC (SpringJDBC etc).

Sometimes I like ORM because to me it's a reduced version of a SQL. And It's helped me in handling my relation models.

For example:

**Scenario**

Here I have a few models in class `Tourism`:

```
class Hotel {..}

class Schedule { ... List<Hotel> hotels; ...}

class Product {... List<Schedule> schedules; ...}
```

My business logic is more complicated; and thus, the class level is greater than 4 and fields are too many.

Imagine making use of SQL for SAVE or UPDATE - it is crazy!

Maybe I should separate the submit product base-info and schedules, etc in the HTML part.

Sometimes I like SQL, because it is powerful, highly efficient. Of course it would depend on the type of database being used.

SQL supports `RECURSIVE QUERY`, solves "TREE" query like "Area" etc.

SQL debug is friendly. Error is just error rather than messy error tips.

They are both in my project.

ORM uses Relation Model, whereas SQL uses complicate modeling like Tree, Report etc.

But I think it's a mess in the project (same method uses SQL and JPA).

And JPA sometimes is either not working or is trouble-some. So I think SQL is better.

I'm wrong with my assertion hereby? Is there another way?

If SQL is better, then how to hanlde complicate relationships in the DAO,

such as the following?

```
INSERT INTO a      (id, name) VALUES (1000,'a');
INSERT INTO a_b    (id, a,name) VALUES (10, 1000, 'b1'), (20, 1000, 'b2');
INSERT INTO a_b_c  (id, a, b, name) VALUES (1, 1000, 10, 'c1'), (2,1000, 20, 'c2');
```

I apologize for my English. I wish you could understand me thus far. :)

Comment: Take a look at jOOQ. It provides an interesting third way: Typesafe SQL.

Comment: "*ORM uses Relation Model, whereas SQL uses complicate modeling like Tree*" - doesn't make sense. SQL is built around the idea of the relational model. Plus: an ORM uses an **object-oriented** layer _over_ a relational model. In your Java code you don't see the relational model any more - only the object model

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: *"In your Java code you don't see the relational model any more - only the object model"* - [Which some claim is the same thing](http://queue.acm.org/detail.cfm?id=1961297)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [both JPA (e.g. Hibernate) and SQL (e.g. jOOQ)](http://vladmihalcea.com/jooq-facts-from-jpa-annotations-to-jooq-table-mappings/) in the same Data Access layer.

1. Hibernate allows you to dynamically update all *DML* statements whenever you add/remove entity properties. The entity graph model is convenient for write operations and the [concurrency control mechanisms](http://vladmihalcea.com/preventing-lost-updates-in-long-conversations/) allow you to prevent [lost updates](http://vladmihalcea.com/a-beginners-guide-to-database-locking-and-the-lost-update-phenomena/).
2. SQL (in general) and jOOQ (in particular) are mandatory to leverage the most of your current underlying database. SQL is indeed powerful and just because you are using an ORM tool, it doesn't mean you won't have to use native queries. For read operations and data projections that require [*window functions*](https://vladmihalcea.com/why-you-should-definitely-learn-sql-window-functions/), *common table expressions*, *derived table expressions* you SHOULD use SQL.